# Psychology behind SE?

Tags: human-factors

I'm not yet that SE experienced user but one thing I've observed is that If I give a good answer then I get upvotes on my other questions too.But as I give a comment that may seem to be bad to the OP I get downvotes on my other questions.

> As in real world example can be as:
>  A bad action against someone
>   resulting in their bad action against the person.

Is there a unique word for this in psychology ?

Comment: Retaliation? This question suffers extremely from lack of initial research, and is not based in cognitive sciences in any way. Therefore, it got put on hold. You can edit your question to incorporate further details you find which might lead to a more refined question.